# Can't submit ios app for review after installing osx security update

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed the latest osx security update (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207130) and tried to archive an update for my ios app. The archive was successful. However, after uploading the build to itunes connect with the Application loader,  I received the following email :

[image]

When trying to submit my app for review I got this other error message :

[image]

I am clearly not running any beta build of macos or xcode. Here is my setup : OSX El Capitan 10.11.6, Xcode 7.3 (7D175)

Any one having the same issue? How did you get around this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue after I applied Security Update 2016-002 released yesterday. Did you finally solve it?

Comment: Try install Xcode 8 and use its application loader (v3.6) to upload your build (exported .ipa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there have been many errors at **iTunes Connect** which Apple still can't solve on **macOS Sierra (10.12)** when uploading archives(build) of our applications,

> *You must use Xcode 8 no matter what on macOS Sierra*

**These are common errors that is happening when we upload our archive from Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra (10.12)**

1. ERROR ITMS - 90163 (No.App bundle found)
2. Now your problem

Changing the build version or Xcode version from info.plist doesn't seen to worked. Believe me, I have tried many alternative hacking ways. Finally I gave up. Instead install Xcode 8 and Xcode 7.3.1 parallel on my mac because I am not ready for migration.

Archive your build from Xcode 7.3.1 and export it's ipa from App Store Release. Then, use Application Loader of Xcode 8 to upload your build to App Store.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50064), try this:

> I was able to submit without warnings or errors by digging into the
>   .xcarchive and modifying the info.plist of the app.
>   Change the key
>   `<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key> 
>   <string>15G1004</string>`
>   to the value for the original 10.11.6
>
> `<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
>   <string>15G31</string>`
>
> Then export the IPA or submit to the app store as usual.

*I didn't test so it could not fix your problem.*

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. I modified the info.plist file but still had the same error when I submitted the build for review

Answer (score 0):

From [this same thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50064), this seems to be a recurrent issue when Security Updates are released.

If @marco-santarossa's method does not work, you can wait for Apple to update iTunes Connect so that they accept the new OS build version, or contact support hoping they can speed this up.

I did and after a few hours the same build I had uploaded was submitted for review.